# Azure SAS Token not working with Azure.Storage.Blobs BlobServiceClient

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I am using `Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.1.0` library. I am generating a Blob Level SAS token using user delegation with Azure Service Principal Credentials, and trying to upload a blob using SAS Token generated.
I have followed exactly [this code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs) sample from Azure to generate the SAS Token.

Here is the code I am using to create SAS Token :

```
string blobEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net", storageProviderSettings.AccountName);

        TokenCredential credential =
            new ClientSecretCredential(
                storageProviderSettings.TenantId,
                storageProviderSettings.ClientId,
                storageProviderSettings.ClientSecret,
                new TokenCredentialOptions());

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobEndpoint),
                                                            credential);

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        var delegationKey = await blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7));
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            BlobName = blobName,
            Resource = "b",
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(expirySeconds)
        };
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.All);
        // if (withDownloadAccess) {
        //     sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);
        // }
        // if (withDeleteAccess) {
        //     sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Delete);
        // }
        Console.WriteLine(sasBuilder.Permissions);
        var sasQueryParams = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(delegationKey, storageProviderSettings.AccountName).ToString();
        UriBuilder sasUri = new UriBuilder()
        {
            Scheme = "https",
            Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", storageProviderSettings.AccountName),
            Path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", containerName, blobName),
            Query = sasQueryParams
        };

        BlobServiceClient service = new BlobServiceClient(sasUri.Uri);

        await service.GetPropertiesAsync();

        Settings tmpUploadCredentials = CreateTemporaryAzureStorageProviderSettings(sasUri, storageProviderSettings);

        Console.WriteLine(tmpUploadCredentials.ConnectionString);
        return tmpUploadCredentials;
```

The SAS Token is created and the Get Blob is working perfectly fine if i keep it in browser but using the `BlobServiceClient` if i am trying to upload the file or perform any action it is now working.
To check if it is authenticated or not i have written this line `await service.GetPropertiesAsync();` which is throwing the following error:

[image: This is the error]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my test, `service.GetPropertiesAsync();` is an action on account. It means that it will call the [Get Blob Service Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-service-properties) rest api to get the properties of the account's blob service. However, when you create `BlobServiceClient`, you provide the blob url. The blob do not support the action. So you will get the error.  It will want to to get the properties of a blob, please call the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties). So, please update your code as following code

```
 BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(sasUri, null);
blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet#get-the-user-delegation-key

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim!!! Was making a simple mistake, trying to create blobServiceClient with the Sas URI which doesn't make sense, it should be BlobClient. But in the link i have pasted they were creating BlobServiceClient with the URI. It misguides many people i have raised an issue in azure-sdk-net for that. Again Thanks a lot man!!